# Need help with pseudo code for date format and validation

Tags: logic

I have to write a pseudo code for an algorithm that receives a date in format of dd/mm/yyyy and validate it, this will repeat until users inputs "no". 
The validation has to check for:

- leap year check for february
- month in range of 1-12
- day in range of 1-31 and according to number of days for respective
  month

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Also, this might not be suited for the math section.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare checkDate
LeapYear is boolean
Year is integer
Month is integer
Day is integer
flag is integer
input Date
Year = val(mid(Date, 7, 4))
Month = val(mid(Date, 4, 2))
Day = val(mid(Date, 1, 2))
flag = 0
if Year Mod 4 = 0 then
 LeapYear = True
end If
if Month < 13 then
if Month = 1 Or Month = 3 Or Month = 5
Or Month = 7 Or Month = 8 Or Month = 10
Or Month = 12 then
 if Day <= 31 then
 flag = 0
 else
 flag = 1
 end if
 else
 if Month = 4 Or Month = 6 Or Month =
9 Or Month = 11 then
 if Day <= 30 Then
 flag = 0
 else
 flag = 1
 end if
 end if
 end if
else
 flag = 1
end if
if LeapYear = True then
 if Month = 2 then
 if Day <= 29 then
 flag = 0
 else
 flag = 1
 end if
 else
 if Month = 2 then
 if Date <= 28 then
 flag = 0
 else
 flag = 1
 end if
 end if
 end if
end if
if flag = 0 then
Print "date is correct"
else
Print "date is incorrect"
end if'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is extremely pseudo-code ... letting 'oops' mean 'return an error'

```
input date
day = int(date[0,1])
month = int(date[2,3])
year = int(date[4,7])
if month > 12 or month < 01:
   oops
elif month == 1,3,5,7,8,10,12:
   if day > 31 or day < 01:
      oops
elif month == 4,6,9,11
   if day > 30 or day < 01:
      oops
elif month == 2
   if year % 4 == 0 or (year % 100 != 0 and year % 1000 == 0) #check for leap year
      if day > 29 or day < 01:
         oops
   else
      if day > 28 or day < 01:
         oops
```

Comment: @naslundx i am not sure where to start so i have not tried.

Comment: @ian i do not understand the "oops" part and int(date[0,1]), int(date[2,3]), int(date[4,7])